# How can I "check" if the channel is private?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I "check" if the channel is private in discord.py rewrite, 
I even saw a similar question but the answer was not working :<

Answer (score 2):

Check if the channel is an instance of the [`PrivateChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.abc.PrivateChannel) abstract base class:

```
from discord.abc import PrivateChannel
from discord.ext.commands import Bot    

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def isprivate(ctx):
    await ctx.send(isinstance(ctx.channel, PrivateChannel))

bot.run("token")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solve it like this. :)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        print("message is privat...")
    else:
        print("message is not private...")
```